# The meaning of ua and mw in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I read wiki's page's source code with web browser, there is some JavaScript code:

```
    var mediaWikiLoadStart = (new Date()).getTime();
function isCompatible(ua) {
    if (ua === undefined) {
        ua = navigator.userAgent;
    }
    return !((ua.indexOf('MSIE')!==-1 && parseFloat(ua.split('MSIE')[1]) < 8) || (ua.indexOf('Firefox/')!==-1 && parseFloat(ua.split('Firefox/')[1]) < 3) || (ua.indexOf('Opera/')!==-1 && (ua.indexOf('Version/')===-1 ? parseFloat(ua.split('Opera/')[1]) < 10 : parseFloat(ua.split('Version/')[1]) < 12)) || (ua.indexOf('Opera ')!==-1 && parseFloat(ua.split(' Opera ')[1]) < 10) || ua.match(/BlackBerry[^\/]*\/[1-5]\./) || ua.match(/webOS\/1\.[0-4]/) || ua.match(/PlayStation/i) || ua.match(/SymbianOS|Series60/) || ua.match(/NetFront/) || ua.match(/Opera Mini/) || ua.match(/S40OviBrowser/) || (ua.match(/Glass/) && ua.match(/Android/)));
}
var startUp = function() {
    mw.config = new mw.Map(true);
    mw.loader.addSource({
        "local": "//bits.wikimedia.org/en.wikipedia.org/load.php",
        "metawiki": "//bits.wikimedia.org/meta.wikimedia.org/load.php"
    });
```

I don't understand what ua and mw is. I don't see their definition in source code and I don't find them in google. So what does ua and mw mean?

Comment: This is javascript code not PHP

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com Thank you. I see a "mediawiki" tag was added. I don't know the relationship between javascrip and mediawiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MediaWiki context, `mw` is a global object containing [a number of Javascript methods and properties](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/mw), that other javascript modules can make use of. If, for instance, you are adding Javascript code to `MediaWiki:Common.js`, you will always be able to access the `mw` variable. (Read more about MediaWiki JS modules [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Default_modules).)

The `mw.config` in your code snippet contains [a number of configuration values](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript#mw.config), such as `mw.config.skin`, with the name of the currently used skin.

The `mw.loader` is an interface for the [MediaWiki Resource loader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader), that can be used to load other Javascript modules, while handling dependencies, minifications, etc for you.

As for `us`, it is, as already pointed out, defined right in front of you...

Comment: Thank you for your  patience and detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see their definition in source code

It's right in front of you...

parameter of the function:

```
function isCompatible(ua)
```

and its default value:

```
ua = navigator.userAgent;
```

Comment: Sorry and Thank you, I'm also new to javascript. What does mw mean?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Just as `ua` doesn't. Read the code.